# Dynamically adding images to the gridview in android

Tags: android, gridview

I am trying to add images from my sd card in android to gridview. I am reading images using this method:

```
     public void getImages()
        {
            File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "AppsCameraSpy");
            if(mediaStorageDir.exists())
            {
                String[] strings = mediaStorageDir.list();
                imageTitles = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(strings));
                Log.d(TAG, "the files are: " + imageTitles);

            }
            try
            {
                for(File file : mediaStorageDir.listFiles())
                {
                    files.add(file);
                    images.add(BitmapDrawable.createFromPath(file.getAbsolutePath()));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d(TAG,"Got some exceptoin ");
            }
        }
```

Now, I am passing above values to the gridview:

```
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery, container, false);

        gridView = (GridView)view.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        Log.d(TAG,"I am gallery");
        getImages();

        gridView.setAdapter(new GridViewAdapter(getActivity(),images,imageTitles,files));

        return view;
    }
```

Everything works fine. But, the issue is if new images are added to the folder `AppsCameraSpy`, my grid view is not showing them.

Since I am setting adapter in `onCreateView`, which is called only once, as per the life cycle.

Now, how should I modify my code to dynamically add images to my gridview.

Please help me to answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

I have added some new code in your existing. I hope The following code will work for you

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery, container, false);

    gridView = (GridView)view.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    Log.d(TAG,"I am gallery");
    getImages();

    GridViewAdapter adapter = new GridViewAdapter(getActivity(),images,imageTitles,files);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

    Handler handler = new Handler();

    final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            getImages();
            adapter.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
        }
    };
    handler.postDelayed(r, 1000);


    return view;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. But adding: `gridViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` in onResume worked.`public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        gridViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Log.d(TAG,"Hello from gallery fragment on resume");
    }`